# Delete Krunner history

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, krunner

I often use Krunner to quickly access often used files. Lately I changed my storage partition mount point, from `/storage/` to `/mount/storage/`, but Krunner didn't record the change. It stills provides me a link to the old location, making it useless.

How can I delete Krunner's history or cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Launch *KRunner* and click on the highlighted icon

[image: KRunner settings]

- In the new window that opens, click on *Clear history*

[image: Clear KRunner history]

Note that even these steps may not help *KRunner* see the new location because *baloo*, which *KRunner* depends on, doesn't index areas other than the user's home folder unless set to do so.

See https://community.kde.org/Baloo/Configuration in this regard.

It maybe possible to use the GUI provided by *System Settings* > *Search* to remove the desired location from the list of *excluded* items.

In the image below, a USB drive, "TOSHIBA EXT" is not being indexed.

[image: Excluded device]

Be prepared for some heavy CPU/RAM usage until the device is fully indexed!

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me was to remove the baloo index and lock files manually.

```
rm -f ~/.local/share/baloo/index*
```

Do not worry about the database getting deleted. Baloo will reindex the filesystem on next startup.
Also you can run this command to reindex after deleting.

```
balooctl check
```

Answer (score 0):

The file location for Distro: KDE neon 20.04 5.23 base: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal:

```
/home/<username>/.local/share/krunnerstaterc
```

or

```
~/.local/share/krunnerstaterc
```

`krunnerstaterc` is a comma separated file.

For the specific case of the original post the following command would fix the issue:

```
sed -i 's/\/storage\//\/mount\/storage\//g' ~/.local/share/krunnerstaterc
```

For those using `vim` some useful commands:

Note: I prefer : over / in my substitute commands. If you are unfamiliar with `vim`, you must press `:` to get to the command line, then type the command (or paste with Ctrl+Shift+v).

:`%s:,:,\r:g` = Separate each item to a line.

:`%s:/storage/:/mount/storage/:g` = replace /storage/ with /mount/storage/ in entire file. (note: if you use / instead of : then replace / with \/ that's backslash slash without a space).

:`g:search_term:d` = delete entire line containing search_term.

:`%s:,\n:,:g` = Combine lines again. Do this last. then save and quit: :`wq`

Note: I used `\r` in the first command and `\n` in the last command. I'm not clear on the difference; it is just what worked for me.